# BASH Disk Status: integer expression expected

Tags: linux, bash, disk, disk-io

This is a part of my bash script:

```
    # Checking disk
    for disk in $disks
    do
      # Creating a array with results
      declare -a status=(`smartctl -a -d ata $disk | awk '/Reallocated_Sector_Ct/ || /Seek_Error_Rate/ { print $2" "$NF }'`)
      # Checking that we do not have any Reallocated Sectors
      if [ "${status[1]}" -ne 0 ]
        then
        echo "$mname Warning: Disk $disk has errors! ${status[0]} ${status[1]} ${status[2]} ${status[3]}. Following complete smartctl output." >> diskerror.log
        smartctl -a -d ata $disk >> $logloc/diskerror.log
        failed=("${failed[@]}" "$disk")
        sendm="1"
      fi
done
```

When i run the script, bash return the follow error: **disk_status.sh: line 38: [: : integer expression expected**

The error line is: `if [ "${status[1]}" -ne 0 ]`

Someone can help with this error?

Comment: Keep in mind that `Seek_Error_Rate` and `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` are not the only SMART parameters you should check when estimating the condition of a hard drive.

Comment: In order to answer your question we need to know what `$status` (or at least `${status[1]}` looks like. Use `set -x` to enable debugging mode and you will be able to find out what has caused your problem.

Comment: Most likely, `${#status[@]}` is 0 or 1, so `${status[1]}` just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use string comparison instead numeric:

```
if [ "${status[1]}" != "0" ]
```

And check you status value (you are not getting a numeric value in all cases)

Comment: If there's no data, it reports `-`, rather than a number which is probably where the issue occurs